# Why does the error occur when parsing http://www.bashinform.ru/?

Tags: python, parsing

All sites except this are parsing, but here with a delay of about 10 seconds,

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  return response.read()

def main():
  print(get_html('http://bashinform.ru/news/'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

the following error occurs:

Traceback (most recent last call last):
File "D: \ Timur \ OpenServer \ domains \ Parser \ parser.py", line 13, in
main ()
File "D: \ Timur \ OpenServer \ domains \ Parser \ parser.py", line 9, in main
print (get_html ('bashinform.ru/news'))
File "D: \ Timur \ OpenServer \ domains \ Parser \ parser.py", line 5, in get_html
response = urllib.request.urlopen (url)
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ urllib \ request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open (url, data, timeout)
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ urllib \ request.py", line 526, in open
response = self._open (req, data)
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ urllib \ request.py", line 544, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ urllib \ request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func (* args)
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ urllib \ request.py", line 1346, in http_open
return self.do_open (http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ urllib \ request.py", line 1321, in do_open
r = h.getresponse ()
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ http \ client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
response.begin ()
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ http \ client.py", line 297, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status ()
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ http \ client.py", line 258, in _read_status
line = str (self.fp.readline (_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
File "C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ lib \ socket.py", line 586, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into (b)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Attempt to connect was unsuccessful, because from another computer for the required time did not receive the desired response, or the already established connection was broken because of the incorrect response of the already connected computer
[Finished in 19.5s]

Comment: `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] `.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use requests module

```
import random
import requests

agents = [
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)']
headers = {"User-Agent":random.choice(agents)}

url = "http://bashinform.ru/news/"
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response.text)

'<!doctype html>\n<html lang="ru">\n........
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot

Answer (score 0):

The error `WinError 10060` means that you were unable to connect successfully to the host. When I try visiting the website in my browser, the browser prepends `www` to the url (your python code won't do this automatically). Try changing the url to `http://www.bashinform.ru/news/` (include the `www`).

Comment: The same error, but also appeared Corporation \ PhysX \ Common; C: \ Windows \ system32; C: \ Windows; C: \ Windows \ System32 \ Wbem; C: \ Windows \ System32 \ WindowsPowerShell \ v1.0 \; C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Common Files \ Acronis \ SnapAPI \; C: \ Program Files \ nodejs \; C: \ Program Files \ Git \ cmd; C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \ Scripts \; C : \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36-32 \; C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Local \ Microsoft \ WindowsApps; C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm; C: \ Users \ 1 \ AppData \ L...]